# my animated gif (with alpha) is opaque on top of my Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

The same gif shows well on other pages, but not on the jQuery SimpleModal control. 
The issue repeats in IE, FireFox, Chrome.

```
$("#id_MainImg").attr("src", "img/loading_.gif");

// first, show modal, and processing clock.
$("#id_show_individual").modal('', {
    closeHTML:"",
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        borderColor:"#fff",
        height:160,
        padding:0,
        width:350
    },
    overlayClose:true
});
```

This is how I show first the processing time passing. This is just until I get the results from the server.

[image]

Then I change it to the correct image.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Have some code we can look at?

Comment: edit: added the looks + the code that shows the image

Comment: You have "backgroundColor: #fff" in your script. Is that applying a background colour to the gif container? Hard to tell without the HTML.

Comment: that doesn't affect the result

Comment: I solved the problem by giving up the tranparency, and painting the transparent area as the background. But this is not a solution of course